# meaning of word + 上にて

Tags: grammar, jlpt, suffixes, particle-にて

In one of n3 jlpt questions I saw a question with a strange usage of noun + 上にて.

> ただいまホームページ（　）、アルバイトを募集しています。
>
> 3) 上にて

I understand にて has similar meaning and usage as で。
However, why in this case do we say ホームページ上にて instead of ホームページにて？

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an example of how 〜上{じょう} can be suffixed to various kinds of media, similar to how we say “**on** television” or “**on** the internet” in English. Note that `〜上` can also be used for books/magazines, even though it would be “**in** a book/magazine” in English.

Examples:

- テレビ上に映し出される映像
- ラジオ上での対談
- 雑誌上のインタビュー
- パソコン上に保存してあるファイル
- パンフレット上に書いてあります etc.

Interestingly, the `上` can be removed from all the examples above, and the meanings will basically remain the same (aside from some minor differences in nuance).

So ホームページにて or ホームページで are also acceptable. To the Japanese mind, にて/で can feel a little bit more like “**at** the website”, as opposed to “**on** the website” when saying 上で/上にて.