# Comparison Japanese / Mandarin : postpositions

Tags: grammar, comparison

I saw a sentence that goes like this : 利用上の注意

In Chinese, we have [similar constructions](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/50896/how-to-analyze-phrases-like-%E7%88%90%E5%AD%90%E8%A3%A1%E7%9A%84%E7%85%A4%E7%90%83%E5%BE%88%E5%A4%9A-postposition-%E7%9A%84/50905#50905) were a noun is followed by a postposition (although the exact syntactic category is debated), followed by a subordinator, followed by a noun : 爐子裡的煤球很多 lúzǐ lǐ de méiqiú hěnduō : stove inside SUB briquette very numerous : 'Briquettes in the stove are numerous.'

- What is the exact translation of the Japanese sentence?
- Is this construction frequent in Japanese?
- How this 上 in the sentence is analyzed in Japanese grammar? Is it a postposition? Or does it form a whole with 利用?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the exact translation of the Japanese sentence?

Common translations are "Usage Note", "Caution", etc. A very literal translation would be "Attention on Using".

> Is this construction frequent in Japanese?

Yes, it's common, especially in formal sentences. Note that the physical meaning of "on top of" or "above" has been more or less lost.

- [I need help analyzing the phrase 発音上の](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61291/5010)
- [How to pronounce 上 with the meaning of "when"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/52249/5010)
- [What is the meaning and pronunciation of 上 in the following sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/83352/5010)
- [meaning of word + 上にて](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29781/5010)
- [What does it mean to be "over a law"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4329/5010)

> How this 上 in the sentence is analyzed in Japanese grammar? Is it a postposition? Or does it form a whole with 利用?

It's a postposition (aka suffix) because it can directly follow many nouns. It's used in various ways as shown above.

Comment: As a quick note, the English words _"on"_ or _"upon"_ can be used in ways that match this usage of 上.  For the sample phrase 「利用上【りようじょう】の注意【ちゅうい】」, the 上 would probably be translated as _"when"_, as in _"Cautions **when** Using"_, I do see that _"Cautions **on** Using"_ garners [not a few Google hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cautions+on+using%22).

Comment: Thank you Naruto and Eiríkr Útlendi for your help! Just to be sure, here 利用 is a noun, right? Are certain any similar sentences where the element is this position is clearly a noun?

Comment: @starckman I think the pages I linked above have many examples. For example 法律上の means "legal".

Comment: Oh, ok, sorry I was a bit in a hurry when responding, and left to after looking carefully to the links. Thank you very much!

Comment: @naruto Keeping the same construction Noun + Postposition/Suffix + Noun, is it possible to have a postposition/suffix other than 上? In Chinese, it is possible to have very different Postposition/Suffix like 裡 'in', 後 'behind', 下 'under', etc.

Comment: @starckman 下 is a suffix with its own usages, e.g., 意識下の "subconscious", 庇護下の "under protection", 水面下の "under the hood / behind the scenes" etc. 裡 and 後 are not Japanese suffixes.

Comment: "裡 and 後 are not Japanese suffixes.", sure, but Japanese has the equivalents 中 and 後ろ and also others like 外, 前, etc.